# Clear Form Input Inside ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

A part of our website includes users replying to reviews posted by other users. All replies(inputs) are bound to the same ng-model. In the HTML code, there's a form that is repeated, over and over again using ng-repeat.  The problem is that after a user posts a reply the form doesn't get cleared, so the next user replying to the review, is left with a box that includes the review of the previous user, and therefore has to override it.

Here's our HTML code:

```
<li ng-repeat="reply in review.replies">

    <div class="comment-avatar">
        <img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="comment-head">
            <h6 ng-if="reply.authorType == 'user'" class="comment-name">{{reply.user.name}}</h6>
            <h6 ng-if="reply.authorType == 'business'" class="comment-name by-author"> {{business.name}}</h6>

            <span style="margin-top: 10px">{{reply.timestamp | date: 'd MMM, yy h:mm a ' }} 
                <i ng-click="deleteReply(review, reply)" class="delete glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-content">
            {{reply.reply}}
        </div>

    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: maybe you want to `$setPristine` your form controller once reply is posted?

Comment: @tanmay already tried it. Didn't work.